# Comparing List to another List and get matches

Tags: c#

Not sure if I'm overlooking something, but then again it is 8am and haven't had my coffee.

I'm trying to get a List to compare with another list

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var products = new List<product>() {
                new product(){ Id = 1, Name="foogear", Price = 20 },
                new product(){ Id = 2, Name="foobeam" , Price = 23},
                new product(){ Id = 3, Name="foowrench" , Price = 25},
                new product(){ Id = 4, Name="foonut", Price = 27 },
                new product(){ Id = 5, Name="foobar", Price = 29 }
        };
        var products2 = new List<product>() {
                new product(){ Id = 1, Name="foogear", Price = 20 },
                new product(){ Id = 5, Name="foobar", Price = 29 }
        };
        // string[] array = { "foobar" };

        // List<string> listA = new List<string>();
        // listA.Add("foobar");     

        for (int i = 0; i < products2.Count; i++)
        {
            //get all products whose name is Bill
            var prodNames = from s in products
                            where s.Name == products2(i,1)
                            select s;    
            foreach (var product in prodNames)
            {
                var test = product.Price + 641;
                Console.WriteLine(product.Id + ", " + product.Name + " "+ test);
            }
        }
    }
}

public class product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
}
```

Tried changing (i,1) to [i]

```
var prodNames = from s in products
                where s.Name == products2[i]
                select s;
```

as well as changing it to products2.Name.

Selecting and comparing these from a normal list

```
//List<string> listA = new List<string>();

//  listA.Add("foobar");
```

works perfectly fine.

What am I overlooking here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using `List<string>` then `product2[i]` is returning string which is used in `Where` clause, but when you using `List<Product>` then you need to use `product2[i].Name` or better way is to use `foreach` loop to iterate over `products2` list and filter `products` list based on each element from `product2`.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        ..
     
        foreach(var product in product2)
        {

           //get all products whose name is same as product.Name
           var filteredProducts = products
               .Where(x => x.Name.Equals(product.Name)); //Instead of product2(i,1);

           foreach(var filtedProduct in filterProducts)
             Console.WriteLine(filteredProduct);
           ...
        }
    }
}
```

To print product details you can `override` `ToString()` function like in `proudct` class,

```
//Use proper naming conventions, like class name starts with capital letter.
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    { 
        return $"{this.Id}, {this.Name} {this.Price + 641}";
    }   
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you! Time for a morning coffee.

Comment: There was no need to delete https://stackoverflow.com/a/67835216/259769 - just test your code before posting and fix it when it is wrong.

Comment: @Enigmativity, I will fix it and will undelete

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use [Enumerable.Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.join?view=net-5.0) via `System.Linq` to join both lists by product name. And the result will filter only the product(s) whose name appeared in both lists.

### SOLUTION 1

```
using System.Linq;


var filteredProducts = products
    .Join(products2,
        product => product.Name,
        product2 => product2.Name,
        (product, product2) => product)
    .ToList();
        
foreach (var filtedProduct in filteredProducts)
    Console.WriteLine($"{filtedProduct.Id} {filtedProduct.Name} {filtedProduct.Price + 641}");
```

### SOLUTION 2

```
using System.Linq;

var filteredProducts = (from product in products
                        join product2 in products2 on product.Name equals product2.Name
                        select product)
                       .ToList();

foreach (var filtedProduct in filteredProducts)
    Console.WriteLine($"{filtedProduct.Id} {filtedProduct.Name} {filtedProduct.Price + 641}");
```