# getting data from files in a directory in C#, but i want to arrange/sort it

Tags: c#

I have a code written where I am getting metadata (date created, date last modified, etc) from all files in a directory, and I am printing out the file's last modification date, and it's name.

I want it so that the output is arranged/sorted in the order of the files' last modification date(in descending order)...
how would I do this?

Here is a snippet of my code:(it is a console application)

```
foreach (string filepath in Directory.GetFiles(mainPath))
{
    lastModified = File.GetLastWriteTime(filepath);
    lastModifiedDate = lastModified.ToString().Remove(11);
    fileName = Path.GetFileName(filepath);
    fileName = fileName.Substring(0, fileName.Length - 4);
    fileProperties.Add(new FileProperties { lastModifiedDateofFile = lastModifiedDate, fileName = fileName });                             
}
fileProperties.ToArray();
//(and then I print it, which comes at a later point in the code which is why I am not showing it here, it was just a Console.WriteLine command)
```

Also, the **fileProperties** thing is a list of instances of a class I've made(and later gets converted to an array, as you can see)... it has two properties, and they are the **lastModifiedDateofFile**, and **fileName** properties, both are strings.

Comment: fileProperties.OrderByDescending(x => x.lastModifiedDate).ToArray() ?

Comment: @shree.pat18, it will not work as `lastModifiedDate` is of type string in OP's question. If you check my answer I suggested to store *only date* instead of converting string and removing `11` characters of from it.

Comment: @NabeelAnsari, why are you doing `.Remove(11)` while converting `lastModifiedDate` to string? Do you want to store only time?

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar yes, the .Remove(11) was to store only the Date

Comment: @NabeelAnsari, so use `.Date` property instead of converting `DateTime` to `string and then remove`(Buggy code). You need  last modified date and time, which you are getting from `GetLastWriteTime()` function. Just store it and apply `OrderByDescending` on it. I did same in my answer. Hope it will help. For more details I added comments for each line

Comment: @NabeelAnsari, Let me know if you need further details regarding my answer

Answer (score 1):

**Important note:** `File.GetLastWriteTime(filepath);` returns `DateTime`, **do not** convert it to string, instead use `.Date` property of `DateTime` to store only date in `lastModifiedDate` property

Once you store `lastModifiedDate` as `DateTime` type, instead of just `fileProperties.ToArray();`, first order your list `fileProperties` to descending using [`OrderByDescending()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderbydescending?view=net-5.0) function from `System.Linq`,

> Sorts the elements of a sequence in descending order.

```
using System.Linq;
...

foreach (string filepath in Directory.GetFiles(mainPath))
{

   //Use .Date property of DateTime.
   //****Actually, you even don't need .Date property, Sorting on DateTime gives precise result as it consider seconds as well.
   lastModified = File.GetLastWriteTime(filepath).Date;

   //Use Path function to get name without extension.
   fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filepath);

   //Instead of storing string as datetime, store as `Datetime`.
   //I would suggest change type of `lastModifiedDateofFile` from string to DateTime
   fileProperties.Add(new FileProperties { lastModifiedDateofFile = lastModified  fileName = fileName });                             
   }

var result = fileProperties
      .OrderByDescending(x => x.lastModifiedDateofFile)  //Order list of fileProperty by desc
      .ToArray(); //Convert to array
```

---

Please, use proper [naming conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/coding-conventions#naming-conventions) while writing your code. As you are a beginner it will help you in the long run

Comment: i did what you said, and i did read some more documentation and stuff and that should work... but, the output shows "fmr1.Program+FileProperties"... i did insert a breakpoint where we are adding stuff to the list, and it is adding "fmr1.Program+FileProperties" for some reason... help?

Comment: @NabeelAnsari `fmr1.Program+FileProperties` is not giving clear idea about the error. Have you checked `result` variable. Does it contain sorted records based on `lastModifiedDateofFile` property?

Comment: Please add proper error and call stack if it is relevant to the question. If not then add a new question with proper details

Comment: i inserted a breakpoint at "var result = *rest of the code*" this time, and here's what is looked like: https://imgur.com/a/1cNgjt6

Comment: It is working fine. `result` is of type `List<FileProperties>`. I believe you are getting `fmr1.Program+FileProperties` on  Console. To print specific values of `FileProperties` class  on console override `ToString()` function. Refer my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/67833875/6299857

Comment: Or update your question and let us know what values you are expecting to print on console. `Console.WriteLine(fileproperty)` will always return `fmr1.Program+FileProperties` something like this

Comment: basically, the list is being added/filled with "fmr1.Program+FileProperties" instead of what it was previously doing, which is the file's name with its last modification date

Comment: update: ok so turns out that i was looking at it, but i wasnt seeing the other values(i.e., the output issue is fixed)...
but it still doesnt seem to be sorting the items by date:/

Comment: @NabeelAnsari, I am not sure what are you talking about. Kindly provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that I can help you in right direction